# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable when calculating z-score

Tags: python, numpy, math, statistics, probability

I'm trying to calculate the z-score and output it to a file from an input file. I'm looking here for reference https://www.statology.org/z-score-python/, however, I keep getting TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable. So how can I calculate the z-score with numpy? Can't find it anywhere online.

```
def calculateZscore(self, input_file, output_file ):
    self.get_text_from_file(input_file)
    for i in self.text:
        data = np.array(i[1:5])
        mean = np.mean(data)
        std = np.std(data)
        get_z_score = 0
        for x in data:
            z_score = (x - mean) / std
            get_z_score = z_score
        float_to_str = list(map(str, get_z_score))
        print(get_z_score)
        w = open(output_file, "w+")
        w.write(stats.zscore(float_to_str))
```

Here's my full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Justin/PycharmProjects/lab_assignment/main.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Justin/PycharmProjects/lab_assignment/main.py", line 44, in main
    get_text.calculateZscore('NCSIDS_ObsExp.txt', 'calculate_z_score.txt')
  File "C:/Users/Justin/PycharmProjects/lab_assignment/main.py", line 19, in calculateZscore
    float_to_str = list(map(str, get_z_score))
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Comment: The error should tell you the problem line.  I suspect the `get_z_score` variable and your attemlt use it with `map`

Comment: A float64 object is a single value derived from a array, most likely through iteration.  You can't iterate again on that number.

Comment: @hpaulj how could I convert it to a string then?

Comment: `str(get_z_score)` - you don't need to iterate or map

Comment: In you loop `for x in data`, you seem to be calculating a zero score for each value, but then you are not storing these values so you will have the z-score for the last value in the list. `get_z_score` should be a list or numpy array that you store each value in.